How can I separate add or edit actions into two different models in one view?
I have following problem: in this one view Trades/Views/Details.cshtml:
@model TradeJournal.ViewModels.TradesJournalsViewModels

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        <h4>Trade</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="row">
           <!--displayed properties below-->
        </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="vw-80">
        @if (Model.Journal != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Journal is not null, rendering partial view.");
            await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/Views/Journals/AddOrEdit.cshtml", this.Model.Journal);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Journal is null.");
            <p>Journal data is not available or the model type is incorrect.</p>
        }

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" class="btn btn-success" asp-route-id="@Model?.Trade.Id">Edit</a> 
    <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back to List</a>
</div>

I want to display for add, edit and view this view from Views/Journals/AddOrEdit.cshtml:
@model TradeJournal.Models.Journal

@{
    ViewData["PageTitle"] = "Journals";
    ViewData["PageActionText"] = "+ Add note";
    ViewData["PageActionUrl"] = "/Journals/AddOrEdit";

    var tools = new[] {
        "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "StrikeThrough",
        "FontName", "FontSize", "FontColor", "BackgroundColor",
        "LowerCase", "UpperCase", "|",
        "Formats", "Alignments", "OrderedList", "UnorderedList",
        "Outdent", "Indent", "|",
        "CreateLink", "Image", "CreateTable", "|", "ClearFormat", "Print",
        "SourceCode", "FullScreen", "|", "Undo", "Redo"
    };
}

<h4>Journal</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <form asp-action="AddOrEdit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"  class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="TradeId"/>

            <div class="mb-3 w-100">
                <ejs-richtexteditor  id="Text" value="@Model.Text">
                    <e-richtexteditor-toolbarsettings items="tools"></e-richtexteditor-toolbarsettings>
                </ejs-richtexteditor>
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Text" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
  
            <div class="mb-3">
                <ejs-button cssClass="w-100" id="submit" type="submit" content="Add note"></ejs-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

But whenever I add or edit note, the compiler wants me to edit Trade details also. How do I separate it?
These are the controllers - TradeController:
public class TradesController : Controller
{
     private readonly AppDbContext _context;
     private readonly ImportTrade _csvImporter; // to do 

     public TradesController(AppDbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
         _csvImporter = new ImportTrade(context);
     }

     // GET: Trades
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {
         return View(await _context.Trades.ToListAsync());
     }

     // GET: Trades/Details/{Id}
     public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
     {
         // nie znaleziono/istnieje id 
         if (id == null) 
             return NotFound();
         
         var trade = await _context.Trades
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

         // nie znaleziono trade
         if (trade == null) 
             return NotFound();
  
         //podlaczanie notatki pod trade
         var journal = new Journal
         {
             TradeId = trade.Id
         };

         //tworzenie viewModelu
         var viewModel = new TradesJournalsViewModels
         {
             Trade = trade,
             Journal = journal
         };

         //zwracamy oba
         return View(viewModel);
     }

     // GET: Trades/AddOrEdit
     public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int id=0)
     {
         // odpala sie 
         if (id == 0) 
             return View(new Trade());
         else 
             return View(_context.Trades.Find(id));
     }

     [HttpPost]
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit([Bind("Id,TransactionOpenDate,TransactionCloseDate,SymbolName,PositionType,PositionVolume,EntryPrice,StopLoss,TakeProfit,Comission,Swap,TradeOutcome,PriceChange")] Trade trade)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid) 
         {
             if (trade.Id == 0) 
                 _context.Add(trade);
             else 
                 _context.Update(trade);

             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = trade.Id });
         }

         var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

         foreach (var error in errors)  
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);

         return View(trade);
    }
}

JournalController:
public class JournalsController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public JournalsController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Journals
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var appDbContext = _context.Journals.Include(j => j.Trade);
        return View(await appDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Journals/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var journal = await _context.Journals
            .Include(t => t.TradeId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

        var trade = await _context.Trades.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == journal.TradeId);

        if (journal == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var viewModel = new TradesJournalsViewModels
        {
            Trade = trade,
            Journal = journal // Zakładamy, że Journal jest powiązany z Trade
        };

        return PartialView("AddOrEdit", viewModel);
    }

    // GET: Journals/AddOrEdit
    public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        // Załaduj listę TradeId do ViewBag
        //ViewData["TradeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Trades, "Id", "Id");

        if (id == 0) 
            return View(new Journal()); // Jeśli id jest 0, zwróć pusty model Journal do widoku
        else
        {
            var journal = _context.Journals.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == id);

            if (journal == null) 
                return NotFound(); // Jeśli id jest różne od 0, znajdź istniejący wpis w bazie danych

            return PartialView("AddOrEdit", journal);
        }
    }

    // POST: Journals/AddOrEdit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit([Bind("Id,Text,TradeId")] Journal journal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (journal.Id == 0)  
                _context.Add(journal);   // Dodaj nowy rekord
            else 
                _context.Update(journal); // Aktualizuj istniejący rekord

            // Zapisz zmiany w bazie danych
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Przekieruj do Trades/Details/{Id}
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Trades", new {id = journal.TradeId});
        }

        // Jeśli model jest nieprawidłowy, zwróć użytkownika do widoku z błędami walidacji
        //ViewData["TradeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Trades, "Id", "Id", journal.TradeId);

        // Logowanie błędów walidacji do debugowania
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return PartialView("AddOrEdit", journal);
    }
}

Also I'd like to add, that I have view model created:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TradeJournal.Models;

namespace TradeJournal.ViewModels
{
    public class TradesJournalsViewModels
    {
        public Trade Trade { get; set; }
        public Journal Journal { get; set; }
    }
}

I expect the code to separate operations between these models (AddOrEdit for journal doesn't activate AddOrEdit for Trades) and display Journal in Views/Trades/Details.

It seems you are a student !    I created for you a test repo, can you please clearfy problem ; https://github.com/m2017atTR/test
